# Компиляция cpp

Tags: c++

Есть программа написана на C++. Цель написать функцию которая компилирует cpp в exe. В комментариях говорили про make файл. Если я не ошибаюсь make файл это порядок компиляции. Если честно то даже не знаю как правильно задать вопрос. В общем программа должна уметь скомпилировать проект созданный и написанный в MVS. Интересует любая информация касательно этого.

Comment: написать функцию или make файл?

Comment: @Илья Чижанов, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @Илья Чижанов: Пункт первый: установите компилятор. Когда установите, напишите нам, какой именно вы установили. В зависимости от этого дальнейшие шаги отличаются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в заголовочном файле cstdlib есть функция system, которая в качестве аргумента принимает shell-команду для исполнения. Например
    system("g++ -o example helloworld.cpp");